# Add Two's Complement Binary 1011 1110 1011 0011 + 0110 1000 1110 and convert to base-16

Tags: binary

I am getting the wrong answer for this practice exercise in my Computer Architecture course. It says, "perform the following arithmatic operations assuming the values are 16-bit two's complement. Give answers in hexadecimal.

$$ 
1011\ 1110\ 1011\ 0011 
+  0110\ 1000\ 1110 \\ \
\\ increase\ bit\ size \\ \ \\
\; \; \; \ 1011\ 1110\ 1011\ 0011 \\
+ 0000\ 0110\ 1000\ 1110 
\\ = 1100\ 0001\ 0100\ 0001 \\ \ \\
1100_2 = C_{16} \\
0001_2 = 1_{16} \\
0100_2 = 4_{16} \\
0001_2 = 1_{16} \\
\to C141_{16}
$$

However, the correct answer is given as $C541_{16}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\; \; \; \ 1011\ 1110\ 1011\ 0011 \\
+ 0000\ 0110\ 1000\ 1110 
\\ = 1100\ 0\mathbf101\ 0100\ 0001 \\ \ \\$$